# Quickest way to iterate through two lists and see if Values match

Tags: c#, performance, linq

I have two separate lists I generate from different databases. I then compare those two by looking for a matching ID, if the ID matches I assign some variables. The issue I am running into is the way I iterate and compare is by using find method in LINQ. This seems very slow when dealing with lots of data. Here is my code

```
   private void GetSerialNumber(POSHData poshData, MerchantTerminal foundTerminal)
    {
        var result = poshData.poshSerialNumbers.Find(x => x.termid == foundTerminal.terminalID);


        if (result != null)
        {
            foundTerminal.terminalSerialNumber = result.terminalSerialNumber;
            foundTerminal.pinPadSerialNumber = result.pinPadSerialNumber;
            foundTerminal.appName = result.appName;
            foundTerminal.appVersion = result.appVersion;
            foundTerminal.pINPadRecord = result.pinPadRecord;
            foundTerminal.terminalRecord = result.terminalRecord;
            foundTerminal.LastTransactionDateTime = result.LastTransaction;

            if (foundTerminal.pinPadSerialNumber.Length == 0)
            {
                foundTerminal.pinPadSerialNumber = result.pinPadSerialNumber;
            }

            switch (result.SettlementType)
            {
                case "2":
                    foundTerminal.PABX = "Journal";
                    break;
                case "3":
                    foundTerminal.PABX = "Batch Close Required";
                    break;
                default:
                    foundTerminal.PABX = "Unknown";
                    break;
            }
            foundTerminal.AdviceText = result.tranAdjust;
            foundTerminal.AuthOnly = result.tranAuthOnly;


        }



    }
```

What would be the fastest and efficient way to do this? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Much quicker != quickest 

Comment: `.Find(...)` runs the predicate against every item in the input set, making it O(n).  You can make this faster by turning the lookup data into a dictionary ahead of time.  The investment up front will pay off later.  Dictionary lookups take constant time, O(1).

Comment: you can use a Hashset instead like Hashset<string>... then use like myHashset.Contains(foundTerminal.TerminalID)... that will return true or false and should be way faster

Comment: @JonathanAlfaro They are using the object identified by the terminal id (`result`), not merely whether it exists.

Comment: @Amy are you suggesting I turn my list into a dictionary as such?    

class POSHData
    {
        public Dictionary<string, POSHSerialNumber> poshSerialNumbers;
        
    }

Comment: No, you should almost never inherit from a dictionary.  `poshData.poshSerialNumbers.ToDictionary(...)`  You just need to lookup items by an id to speed up this one algorithm, not make radical alterations to your data model.

Comment: @Amy thanks! I'm assuming this is what you meant ```var result = poshData.poshSerialNumbers.ToDictionary(x => x.termid == foundTerminal.terminalID);```

Comment: @Adil15 Right, try it out, then you can write an answer to your question and get some rep.  You just need to make that dictionary *once*, up front, and use it in your lookup.

Comment: @Amy is there a way you can show me a code snippet, I feel like I am looking up within the dictionary wrong as I can't seem to assign values from result to my variables

Comment: @Adil15 I assume you are calling this method from inside a loop?  Can you show how you're using this method?

Comment: @Amy just to cinfirm do you mean my GetSerialNumber method or the .ToDictionary method that i would use to compare the two lists. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: Databases are located on the same server? It is SQL Server?

Comment: @Adil15 I was referring to `GetSerialNumber`

Comment: @Amy I got it going no need! Thanks for your help will post answer soon!

Comment: I'm glad to see that answer was posted.

Comment: @Amy sorry was on vacation! This is what I did it made a huge difference in speed!

Answer (score 1):

```
var result = poshData.poshSerialNumbers
    .Where(x => x.Key == foundTerminal.terminalID)
    .FirstOrDefault();
```